# How to generate an Angular component with string at runtime?

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml, ng-template

I have a property pulled from database at runtime that correspond to an Angular selector.

```
this.stringSelector = "<app-hello></app-hello>";
```

What is the best way to render "Hello World" like so?

```
<app-root>
  <app-hello></app-hello>
</app-root>
```

This is good only for html tags, not Angular selectors:

```
<app-root>
  <div [innerHTML]="this.stringSelector | safe: 'html'"></div>
</app-root>
```

The app-hello component does just one thing:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`
})
export class HelloComponent {
/* . . . */
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to generate a component based on a string? What exactly is happening? Can `stringSelector` be a different component from `app-hello`?

Comment: @JunKang Most use-cases I've seen project HTML content into components via innerHTML. However, I have use-cases where I want the view to be dynamically generated based on the strings received.

Comment: Yea, but why. If you just want dynamically generated components/views, just use *ngIf. Or use router-outlet and have the app route to a specific route based on the string received. I can't see why you would want to dynamically generate a component selector in html.

Comment: *ngif-else is good if I want to manage view based on state. Routing is good if I want to render view based on static templates/layouts. Both are good for many use cases I could image. In my use case, one same route can render views composed from different components in any order. These components may have static views but may be "called" at runtime in different combinations to generate views with different usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 6 solved it with a new feature called [Angular Elements](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#Angular).